# WordPress: Enqueuing resources - Meaning of the "handle"?

Tags: php, wordpress

When I enqueue styles or scripts in Wordpress like for example:

```
wp_enqueue_style('style', get_template_directory_uri() . "/style.css");
```

**What's the meaning of the first parameter?**

Here "style" ...

The documentation calls it a handle: [WordPress - wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/)

But I don't understand it's purpose. The name of the file is repeated in the second parameter again.

What can one do with this handle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The handle is a unique name for the style-sheet. For some WordPress styling functions, the handle is required to identify the style-sheet,

e.g. register style with handle wpdocs and **conditionally** add it to template pages

```
$handle = 'wpdocs';
wp_register_style( $handle, get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/css/mycss.css', array(), '', true );

if ( is_page_template( 'template-name.php' ) ) {
   wp_enqueue_style( $handle );
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense.  :)  Thanks a lot!